# C# Unity - How can I clear an InputField

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input-field

I want to clear an InputField in Unity, but I cant get it to work. What I do now is:
    `public InputField inputfieldname;
    inputfieldname.text = "";`

but then it doesnt clear the field until you select it. Is it possible to clear the field totally just by code?

Thanks in advance!
Ablos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem does not exist in the current version of Unity I am running. My advice to you is to update to 5.4.. If you don't want to, then you can select the `InputField` with code then clear it.

```
public InputField inputfieldname;
inputfieldname.Select();
inputfieldname.text = "";
```

You can make this into an extension method.

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static void clear(this InputField inputfield)
    {
        inputfield.Select();
        inputfield.text = "";
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like below:

```
public InputField inputfieldname;
inputfieldname.clear();
```

Comment: Well it's weird, because I am using the newest version of unity. I think it is because of MaterialUI (extention for UI stuff). But it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: you only have to do this:
`inputfieldname.text = "";`
No `inputfieldname.Select();` needed.

Comment: @Ablos I know but you did `inputfieldname.text = "";` in your question but said it didn't work. You said you have to select it for it to work so I did the selection through code (`inputfield.Select();`). I even mentioned in my answer that I do not have that problem.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't think of that. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are using the TextMeshPro version.
Just use legacy.